# How to get the node value

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to fetch the value for `name` attribute but unable to do it.

```
<Person>
    <DOB localDate="2015-07-02" utcDate="2015-07-02" localTime="09:26:00" utcTime="08:26:00" /> 
    <Info name="Bruce Wayne" Country="GB" Zone="3" /> 
</Person>
```

Comment: What's your code that fails?

Comment: **unable to do it**... How? Have you tried any code at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
string str= "";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("Your XML Path");
XmlNodeList elements = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Info");
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
   str= elements[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
}
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for using an XmlDocument, use the newer XDocument instead, linq makes finding xml nodes very easy.

Try this

```
var name = xDoc.Root.Element("Info").Attribute("name").Value;
```